# java: why this binarySearch with comparator is not working?

Tags: java, sorting

Updated: I am trying to use Collections.sort() to sort an arrayList with a comparator parameter.  Then do binarysearch.

```
package collection;

import java.util.*;

public class TryBinarySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           list.add(i);
        System.out.println(list);
        int b = Collections.binarySearch(list, 8);
        System.out.println(b); // a is 8 as expected.

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        System.out.println(list);   

        Collections.sort(list, new
                Comparator<Integer>(){
            public int compare(Integer a, Integer b){
                return b.intValue() - a.intValue();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(list);   //list is reversed as expected.
        int a = Collections.binarySearch(list, 8);
        System.out.println(a); // why a is -1?
    }
}
```

b is 8 as expected;
I made a reverse sorting. My question is why a is -1, instead of 92?

Comment: So, now you've reorganized the question.  This changes things, as before, you weren't trying to sort after your shuffle.

Comment: I sorted the list. I realized that the list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements. I sorted the list in the reverse order and that's why the value of a is -1.

Comment: Read the documentation. `The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering`.

Answer (score 6):

You shuffled the list, so it is not sorted. You must have a sorted list to do a binary search

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Look at the call to binarySearch *before* the sort call... hence why `b` is positive but `a` is not.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Nope, he calls, in this order : `shuffle, binarySearch, sort, binarySearch`

Comment: I thought I can provide a comparator parameter to an unsorted collection. That's that I did. So I have to explicitly sort the list first?

Comment: @TwistedMeadow the comparator won't sort the list, it will just tell to the algorithm in which sense the collection is sorted

Comment: @TwistedMeadow: Did you read the documentation for the `binarySearch` method you're calling?

Comment: Since the question had been changed to reposition the search so that he's now shuffling *then* sorting, this answer isn't as valid as it was earlier.

Answer (score 3):

To perform a binary search, the list must be sorted.  You first shuffled the list, which invalidates the prerequisite of [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-).

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the sort(List, Comparator) method), prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

The algorithm relies on the list being sorted.  So of course when you sort it later, `binarySearch` works.

Comment: It should be stated that the list must be sorted in ascending order.  (Yes, I realize the documentation says it, but let's be explicit about it.)  The OP's new code has a reverse-sorted list.

Answer (score 3):

Binary search only works when the list is already sorted. The way that binary search works is that the algorithm assumes that if the value at its "guess" index is higher than the one we're looking for, the actual index must be lower - and vice versa.

If the collection isn't sorted, that assumption doesn't hold, so the algorithm fails.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) states this very clearly:

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the `sort(List, Comparator)` method), prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search depends on the list you are searching to be in order.  You are explicitly shuffling yours.  Do you mean to *sort* it via the `Comparator` instead?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `binarySearch(list, key)`, the doc says:

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering

Your list is sorted using a custom `Comparator`, and therefore you need to pass it to the call to indicate the search algorithm how to compare item:

```
    Comparator<Integer> cmp = new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b){
            return b.intValue() - a.intValue();
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(list, cmp);
    System.out.println(list);   //list is reversed as expected.
    int a = Collections.binarySearch(list, 8, cmp);
```

For this call, the doc says:

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator